# How to extract date from a timestamp column in H2

Tags: spring, h2

**Table**
[image]

**Objective**
I want to select only those record which matches a specific date (yyyy-MM-dd)
Like : SELECT * FROM WEATHER WHERE CREATED_AT = "2018-11-28"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your request:

```
SELECT * FROM WEATHER WHERE FORMATDATETIME(CREATED_AT,'yyyy-MM-dd') = '2018-11-28'
```

It is a harder to find info about converting timestamp to date without formatting. Sample for finding all tomorrow scheduling tasks:

```
SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE CAST(date_time AS DATE)=DATEADD(DAY, 1, TODAY);
```