# How to group data by distinct date in H2

Tags: sql, date, datetime, h2

I am using the in-memory database H2 and I would like to group data having same date.

The table I want to query defines a non nullable timestamp column :

```sql
create table example
(
    id               bigint generated by default as identity,
    date             timestamp not null,
    label            varchar(255),
    amount           integer   not null,
    primary key (id)
);
```

I would like to group data by distinct date and to be able to count data having a distinct date without consideration of time.

Other vendors like MySQL allows to perform such grouping by using `DATE` function ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date ) :

```sql
select date(date) as day, count(*) as numberOfExamples, sum(amount) as sum
  from example 
 where year(date) = 2021
group by date(date)
order by date(date)
```

A sample resultset obtained with this query :

```
'2021-01-02', '1', '3707'
'2021-01-04', '1', '2729'
'2021-01-05', '1', '1305'
'2021-01-06', '1', '88536'
```

Date function is also supported by Oracle :
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGINU/apa.htm#TGINU762

However, I haven't found any equivalent function in H2 supported functions :
http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html

Do you know how to write an equivalent query in H2 ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I just googled: "h2 extract date from timestamp" and from many results that were returned the first one was: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53521624/how-to-extract-date-from-a-timestamp-column-in-h2.

Comment: `select FORMATDATETIME(date,'yyyyMMdd')  as day, count(*) as numberOfExamples, sum(amount) as sum
      from example 
     where year(date) = 2021
    group by FORMATDATETIME(date,'yyyyMMdd')
    order by FORMATDATETIME(date,'yyyyMMdd')`

Comment: Thanks for the answers : 

* 'formatdatetime(datetime_column, "yyyy-MM-dd")' function is OK
* 'cast(datetime_column as date) is also OK